# Yii2 HTML helpers

Tags: yii2

Использую в контролере HTML:

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\profile;
use app\models\profileSearch;
use app\models\event;
use app\models\desire;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use app\components\userrows;
use yii\helpers\HTML;
?>
```

Далее у меня есть два акшина
public function actionAddEvent()
public function actionAddDesire()

вот в первом все нормально и $eText=HTML::encode($postText);
отрабатывает нормально, там еще есть похожие вызов, все приводить не буду
это самый первый после открывающихся скобок.

во втором на том же месте выдается ошибка:
Class 'yii\helpers\HTML' not found

Подскажите что может быть не так?

Comment: Филькина грамота ... Нормально оформите вопрос и текст пожалуйста. Ничего не понятно

Comment: Если быть более внимательным, то HTML и Html. Почитать стандарты PSR.

Comment: я знаю, писал и так и так, результат один
код одинаков в двух action